# What is the best way to open a persistent (mongo) database connection in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, mongodb, node.js

I am using the node-mongodb-native drivers and I am looking for a way to open a persistent database connection rather than opening/closing it each time.

A simplified connection might look like this...

```
var DB = new mongo.Db('vows', new mongo.Server("127.0.0.1", 27017, {})),
    connection = DB.open(function(err, db) {
       // Here we have access to db
    });
```

How can I make the **db** object accessible to any module in my application? Rather than having to open the connection for every module separately?

Can this be done using module.exports? Or a global variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: Don't use mongoose, Use something like [`mongo-col`](http://github.com/Raynos/mongo-col) or [`mongo-client`](http://github.com/Raynos/mongo-client). Then have a single client open in your application. I have `./client.js` file that exports a properly opened and configured mongo client.

---

[`Mongoose`](http://mongoosejs.com/) is a solid abstraction on top of mongodb that will allow you to handle mongodb more easily. It's a worth a look.

What you really want to do though is re-open your client every time you do anything with mongo.

You don't keep an open connection to any other database.

Just place your `DB` in a module along with some helper / wrapper functions.

Comment: Isn't it too expensive to reopen the client every time?

Comment: @BinWang I am wrong about every thing. You shouldn't use mongoose, it sucks. And you shouldnt reopen the client every time.

Comment: I'm using [generic-pool](https://github.com/coopernurse/node-pool) now. It also opens many clients (connect to mongodb with "poolSize=1" many times) at one time, keep it open and manage the pool itself. Does this affect the benchmark?

Answer (score 5):

My solution:

```
getClient = function(cb) {
    if(typeof client !== "undefined") {
        return cb(null, client);
    } else {
        db.open(function(err, cli) {
            client = cli;
            getClient(cb);
        });
    }
}
```

Now, instead of

```
db.open(function(err, client) {
    ...stuff...
});
```

Do:

```
getClient(function(err, client) {
    ...stuff...
});
```

Your first db call opens a connection, the others use that connection.

BTW: suggestions on checking that client is still alive?

Comment: The way to see the client is still alive is `setTimeout(...)` after call `getClient`, and in the mongo shell, use `db.runCommand({serverStatus: 1}).connections` to see how many connections there are. I don't think the client will still alive.